# Word 2007 Digital Signatures Automation

Tags: delphi, automation, ms-office, signature

I have a Delphi 2007 application that uses Word automation and my boss wants it to control Office/Word signatures. I have no problem adding the signatures, but I would like to delete the signatures and bypass the built-in Office "Remove Signature" dialog box. Calling the Signature.Delete method pauses the execution until the dialog is dismissed. Any suggestions?

Comment: there must be a flag that will not show the dialog

Comment: Did you try `Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` yet

Comment: Yes I did. Even though the doc object has a signatures collection, it seem that all signature functionality is handled at the Office level and not the Word level.